# Two values for one trigonometric function

Tags: trigonometry

We know that trigonometric function like $\mathsf{sin}$, $\mathsf{cos}$ etc. Give one value for one angle. However there may be different (in fact infinite ) angles which give same value of trigonometric functions.

But consider $\mathsf{sin}(270)$, or alike problems. Here if we make $270$ as 
$270= 3 \times 90 +0$. 
Then where to take it- in third or fourth quadrant, 
$\mathsf{cos}$ is negative on third and positive in fourth quadrant. (here $\mathsf{sin}$ transforms into $\mathsf{cos}$)

(In certain books writer takes both positive and negative values but they have chosen all such questions which give zero as answer) .
How to solve this confusion ?

Comment: 270 degrees is exactly on the boundary between third and fourth quadrant, cosine is zero of course.  Or do you ask about sine?  Sine is negative on both the third and fourth quadrants, so also negative on the boundary between.

Comment: You're confusing definitions with mnemonics. The sine of $270^\circ$ is $-1$, the cosine is $0$. Referring to quadrants is useful for reference, but in case you have doubts, use the definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sin(270^\circ) = -1.$

$\cos(270^\circ) = 0.$

The angle $\angle 270^\circ$  refers to the angle that extends from the positive $x$-axis, and terminates along the $-y$-axis which divides the third from the fourth quadrant.

Let's give a quick image of what we have here: $\angle\, 270^\circ$

[image]

So indeed, in the third quadrant $\cos x \lt 0$.  In the fourth quadrant, $\cos x > 0\;$ but $\;\cos(270^\circ) = 0$

You can find the following image by searching Wikipedia for "Unit circle": where you'll find the following image:

[image]

Note that the image shows angles in both degree mode, and in radian mode.  The ordered pairs you see outward most are of the form $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ (which correspond to the ordered pairs $(x, y)$ on the unit circle (see above)), for various angles $\theta$.